# Java Scanner unable to read file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm doing a very simple text-parsing program, using files given to me by a friend.
However, when I open the file using a Scanner like so,

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File(path));
System.err.println(scan.hasNext());
while(scan.hasNextLine())
    System.err.println(scan.nextLine());
System.err.println(scan.next());
```

result:

```
false
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:855)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1364)
at Test.main(Test.java:18)
```

the scanner treats the file(which is some 1400 lines long) as empty.

Can anyone think of any reason a scanner might not be able to see a file? I suspect the fact that the file was imported from a Windows machine to a Linux machine may have something to do with it, but my mind is open to other possibilities

edited for formatting and code errors

Comment: Before you create the scanner, do you get any errors with the creation of the new File?

Comment: The stack trace shown includes a call to `Scanner.next()`, but no such calls is shown in your code snippet. Which line (in your code) the exception is coming from?

Comment: Additional edits for my own cobbled-together example code.

Comment: Hi @Zach, you've asked 4 previous questions but haven't accepted any answers for any of them.  Please consider reviewing your past questions and seeing if any answers answered your question.  You can accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark next to that answer.

Comment: You are correct, Mark. I've gone back and selected answers for all my questions. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem:
Looked at the file byte by byte. found an EOF character in the first byte.
Java was ignoring the rest of the file.

Comment: how did you check file byte by byte

Comment: @Anil - I submitted this 2 years ago! Funny you commented on it now.

I opened up the file using a hex editor. You can find several kinds of free hex editors on the net. Here's one I found with a quick search: http://frhed.sourceforge.net/en/

Comment: So I ran into the same issue, 7 years later. The answer below worked for me, but I don't know how to validate the EOF story. As far as I know EOF characters are only used in memory and not in files. So how did you exactly find the EOF character. Or better what was the hex?

Answer (score 5):

I resolved it using `new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName)))` instead of `new Scanner(new File(fileName))`

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Fisrt guess was wrong

The file might have 1400 lines full of whitespaces.

Comment: The file follows the format of <string>\t<value>\n. There's a combination of text and values.Good guess though.

Comment: Since new line is also considered a whitespace, the file is supposed to have at least 1400 of these, so your first theory does not sound convincing.

Comment: No. Subsequent calls to `hasNext()` and its relatives will return the same result if you don't call `next()` in between. Also, you can see from the output even the first call to `hasNext()` returns false.

Answer (score 0):

it maybe occurred for this problems:

> 1-your file maybe isn't created.
>
> 2-your file is in use for other programs.
>
> 3-the path address is false.